# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 (yes, once again...)

Tags: ios, objective-c++, undefined-symbol

I'm getting crazy about this issue!

One of errors I get is the next one:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_zipOpen", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive CreateZipFile2:] in ZipArchive.o
```

The peace of code when I call that method (I use objective-c++ there just in the case it matters):

```
@implementation ZipArchive
...
-(BOOL) CreateZipFile2:(NSString*) zipFile
{
    _zipFile = zipOpen( (const char*)[zipFile UTF8String], 0 );
}
```

in the `.h` file I have

```
zipFile _zipFile;
```

and in other place:

```
typedef voidp zipFile;
```

where

```
typedef void *voidp;
```

Ok, I know it shouldn't be working probably. But it worked great before. The things changed with the new target I added for unit test.

I'll greatly thankful for any your help!

Comment: Just a wild guess - if you're calling some c++ code from ZipArchive then you could try renaming ZipArchive.m to ZipArchive.mm

Comment: it is already called like that

Comment: ok, I've solved it - few `.c` files where not added to target

Answer (score 1):

Okay, from the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_zipOpen", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive CreateZipFile2:] in ZipArchive.o
```

we can tell that the prototype for zipOpen() function is declared as a C function (`extern "C"`), as its name isn't mangled.

So, there are basically 2 options why this error is coming up:

- The zipOpen() implementation isn't being linked against your program at all (forgot to add the file/library to your build, #ifdef'd out, etc.)
- The zipOpen() implementation is getting C++, not C linkage, for some reason. Maybe you've accidentally placed it inside a namespace, or the .cpp file doesn't include the header with the `extern "C"` declaration of the function.

We can't say which it is based on the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

check wether function declaration inside a header file equals to function prototype in an implementation file